# toctree numbering not shown on external link entries

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs, toctree

I'm currently writing a technical documentation with Sphinx.

I use a numbered toctree. When I insert an external web link in the toctree the rendered entry does not contain a number.

For this toctree :

```
.. toctree::
   :numbered:
   :hidden:
   :maxdepth: 2

   Administration <admin/admin.rst>
   Usage <usage/usage.rst>
   Squash TM - Squash TF Link <tm-tf-link/tm-tf.rst>
   Download <https://squash-tf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/download.html#squash-tf-execution-server>
```

The "Download" entry has for result :

[image: Toctree result]

Does anyone has a tips for me ?

Comment: IMO this is a bug. I couldn't find [anything relevant in their repo](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=toctree+numbered+url+), so I would suggest you create a new issue.

Comment: Indeed, mee too i think it's a bug and don't found anything on their repo on this subject. I asked here before open the bug in case i missed something. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug as @StevePiercy mentioned. I just submitted a bug report on it [here](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/6173). A similar issue is [this](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/3955) one. However, you can set the missing index manually.

```
Hello world
============

.. toctree::
   :numbered:
   :hidden:
   :maxdepth: 2

   Administration <admin/admin.rst>
   Usage <usage/usage.rst>
   Squash TM - Squash TF Link <tm-tf-link/tm-tf.rst>
   4. Download <https://squash-tf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/download.html#squash-tf-execution-server>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for opening the bug. Yes, put it manually is a working turn around waiting for the fix.